# WPF Binding a Listbox to thing that has sub enumerables

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, datatemplate

I have a class like this:

```
public class UIThing {
   public string Name{get;set}
   public IEnumerable<Thing> LotsOfThings;
}
```

I have some of these in a `List` (`List<UIThings>`) and I would like to bind them into a `ListBox` so that the LotsOfThings member is expanded as items in the `ListBox`. Like a list of lists I guess. But I can't get my head around the `DataTemplate` needed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Consider using a GridView and column a with a combobox.

Comment: Sounds like a `TreeView` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may give you the idea to do it:

I recommend you to use `ItemsControl`

```
public class UIThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> LotsOfThings { get; set; }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UIThing item1 = new UIThing() { Name = "A", LotsOfThings = new List<string>() { "1A", "2A", "3A", "4A" } };
    UIThing item2 = new UIThing() { Name = "B", LotsOfThings = new List<string>() { "1B", "2B", "3B", "4B" } };
    UIThing item3 = new UIThing() { Name = "C", LotsOfThings = new List<string>() { "1C", "2C", "3C", "4C" } };
    UIThing item4 = new UIThing() { Name = "D", LotsOfThings = new List<string>() { "1D", "2D", "3D", "4D" } };

    var list = new List<UIThing>() { item1, item2, item3, item4 };
    itemsControl.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

And this is the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,5" Width="auto">
                <ListBox Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding LotsOfThings}" Margin="20,0,0,0" Background="AliceBlue"></ListBox>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**EDIT:** here is the ListBox version

```
<ListBox Name="itemsControl" Margin="0,0,197,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,5"></Label>
                <Border Margin="20,0,0,0" Background="AliceBlue" CornerRadius="10">
                    <ListBox Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding LotsOfThings}" ></ListBox>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, what i really wanted, but didn't make clear, was that i wanted all the items in one listbox. however, i'm now flattening out the result set into a staright list and displaying that.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a GridView can ComboBox

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Main"/>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GroupsMain, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  IsEditable="False" SelectedIndex="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

If you need everything in a single column then a TreeView as suggested byt Matt

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a DataTemplate for your `UIThing`. In that template you will have another ListView that is bound to your `LotsOfThings` list. Then you can add a DataTemplate for your `Thing` class too.